# Pandas, join row from target file based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I need to merge a row from a target DataFrame into my source DataFrame on a fuzzy matching condition that has already been developed, let's call the method `fuzzyTest`. If fuzzy test returns `True`, I want to merge the row from the target file into my source file when matched.

So basically do a left join where the `TARGET COMPANY` passes the `fuzzyTest` when compared to the `SOURCE COMPANY.`

**Source DataFrame**

```
          SOURCE COMPANY
0           Cool Company
1              BigPharma
2            Tod Kompany
3               Wallmart
```

**Target DataFrame**

```
                       TARGET COMPANY
0                        Kool Company
1                           Big farma
2                      Todd's Company
3                              C-Mart
4                           SuperMart
5                          SmallStore
6                             ShopRus
```

Hopefully after mapping through `fuzzyTest` the output would be:

```
                       SOURCE COMPANY       TARGET COMPANY
0                        Cool Company         Kool Company
1                           BigPharma            Big farma
2                         Tod Kompany       Todd's Company
3                            Wallmart                  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

So if your fuzzy logic only compare the two strings on each row, just wrap it as a function that takes in column source and column target.
Make both columns in one dataframe then run:

```
def FuzzyTest(source,target):
    .....
    if ...:
      return target
    else:
      return None

df['Target Company'] = df.apply(lambda x: FuzzyTest(x['Source'],x['Target'])
```

Comment: @X33 Without any details about your "secret" function that you refuse to show, there's nothing more to be said. Please showcase your code - or at least the code that you can show us. Can't expect us to give you an answer without a well presented question.

Comment: @COLDSPEED I don't think you understand the question. This problem is/was completely solvable without needing the `FuzzyTest` function. I told you the input/output & purpose of the function, and there is no need beyond that as it serves no other purpose. I apologize if I just didn't explain that properly.

Comment: Your solution doesn't take into account that the `TARGET COMPANY` isn't always on the same row/index.